# eclipse - how to treat file extension as C-file

Tags: eclipse-cdt

How do I force Eclipse to treat a file-type as a C/C++ file so it'll index them?

My makefiles create `.pp` files for pre-processor output and I want to view those as C/C++ files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a mapping from the `.pp` extension to the `C++ Source File` file type in `Preferences | C/C++ | File Types`.