# eclipse - enable C syntax highlighting but do not treat it as a C-file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I would like to view preprocessed output files in Eclipse with ***C/C++ syntax highlighting***.

So, I configured Eclipse to treat my `.pp` files like `.c` files : [eclipse - how to treat file extension as C-file.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46163332/eclipse-how-to-treat-file-extension-as-c-file)

But my problem now is when I do **Open Declaration** on a symbol, Eclipse includes the `.pp` files in the search that I told it were C/C++ files which I do NOT want.

How do I tell Eclipse to apply ***C/C++ syntax highlighting*** to files `.pp` but to NOT treat them as actual C/C++ files?

Comment: Does checking `Properties | C/C++ Build | Exclude resource from build` on the `.pp` file help (i.e. cause it to stop appearing in Open Declaration results)?

Comment: Or, alternatively, in `Project | Properties | Resource | Resource Filters`, setting up an exclusion filter for all `.pp` files?

Comment: Finally, in `Preferences | C/C++ | Indexer`,  "Index source files not included in the build" may need to be **un**checked for the above to be effective.

Comment: @HighCommander4 the first one did it: click on `build/` folder and `Exclude resource from build`. I didn't touch the indexer as I do want indexing to occur for fast file searching. THanks.

Comment: @HighCommander4 please create the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep the file type association for semantic highlighting and other C/C++ editor features to work.

However, you can exclude the file from consideration for navigation actions like Open Declaration, by checking "Exclude resource from build" in the file's `Properties | C/C++ Build`.