# eclipse cdt - how to "exclude resource from build" a specific suffix

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

In my build artifact folder(s), I generate pre-processed output of each `.c` file `*.pp`. Once a build is done, if I go to my `.c` file(s) and hit `F3 (Open Declaration)` on a `typedef`, the popup contains the original `.h` or `.c` file **and** all the `*.pp` files that included the `.h`.

Obviously, I don't want that.

Someone [said to add all `.*pp` files `Resource > Resource Filters > Exclude all`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46183959/eclipse-enable-c-syntax-highlighting-but-do-not-treat-it-as-a-c-file)

While this does result in the `.pp` files not appearing in the list of places a symbol is defined . . . it also has the side-effect of removing the `.pp` files from view completely so that I can't see or open them at all.

Of course another way to accomplish this is to `Exclude From Build` the build output folder: `Right click > Properties > C/C++ > Exclude Resource from build`. While this removes `*.pp` from the search path for *where is it defined* searches AND does not make it disappear from view . . . this applies to all items with the folder, some of which I might not want to `Exclude From Build`.

**QUESTION**

Is it possible to `Exclude From Build` based on a suffix instead of a folder while at the same time having syntax highlighting **ON** for a given suffix?

Comment: Is `*.pp` registered in _Window > Preferences: C/C++ > File Types_? If yes, remove it.

Comment: @howlger no I want that because sometimes I need to open up those files and have the syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible:

1. Make sure, **`*.pp`** is **not** added/registered **in *Window > Preferences: C/C++ > File Types***
2. Right-click a `*.pp` file and choose ***Open With > Other...***
3. In the *Editor Selection* dialog select the ***C/C++ Editor***, check the checkbox ***Use it for all '*.pp' files*** and click *OK*.

Comment: But then I cannot get syntax highlighting: `Is it possible to Exclude From Build based on a suffix instead of a folder while at the same time having syntax highlighting ON for a given suffix?`

Comment: Applying step 2 and 3 gets you syntax highlighting and more (validated with Eclipse Oxygen).